# Autofac injects null

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I have a very strange problem with Autofac 2.5.2.830 for .NET 3.5:
I user `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes` to register the types in my assemblies:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes("My.*.dll").Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                                         .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

I have several classes that have a dependency on `IConfigService`. A instance of the concrete implementor of this interface is injected to them but on class gets `null` injected.
It looks like some sort of a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug) to me, because I can make go it away using breakpoints. However, even this is non-deterministic: Sometimes, the bug goes away, when I set a breakpoint in the class that normally gets the `null` injected, sometimes the `null` is injected even with the breakpoint. Setting a break point in one of the classes that are created earlier and also have a dependency on `IConfigService` leads to an injection of a value instead of `null` into the problematic class. Even removing a completely unrelated registration from the builder caused the bug to go away once.
However, one thing seems to be constant: It is always the same class that receives the `null`.

I have no idea where to begin troubleshooting this problem. Is something like this known? What might be the reasons for a `null` injection?

**UPDATE**
Oh my, this is stupid...

The constructor looks like this:

```
public EmailNotifier(IConfigurationService configService)
{
    _mailServerAddress = _configService.Get(Resources.MailServerAddress,
                                            Resources.DefaultSenderAddress);
    _configService = configService;
}
```

When run, this gave me a `NullReferenceException` in the first line of the constructor, because `_configService` was `null`. It looks like, when I set the breakpoint, I sometimes checked whether `configService` is `null` and sometimes whether `_configService` is null. Because of this it looked like sometimes I got `null` injected and sometimes not.

**SUMMARY**
This is NOT a problem with Autofac, because `null` was never injected. `configService` always had a value.

Comment: Can you post some code for "the same class that receives the null." - especially the constructor(s). Can you also confirm that the null can definitely be seen if you put a breakpoint in the constructor - not that it could be some overwritten somewhere later? My *guess* is that something is going wrong in the class somewhere.

Comment: @Stuart: Thanks for your comment. It made me strip down the ctor, so I could copy it hier to SO and I found the error this way. Please see the update... ;-)

Comment: Nah - let's put it up as an answer :) (I've done this myself several times... although normally it's because I've not copied the reference across to the member variable) and I'm sure there's a fair chance that others will come along googling the same problem :) It's not "so stupid" - it's the human condition!

Comment: @Stuart: Thanks for making me feel a little bit better... ;-)

Comment: @Daniel phew! You had me worried there for a second :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post some code for "the same class that receives the null." - especially the constructor(s)

Can you also confirm that the null can definitely be seen if you put a breakpoint in the constructor - not that it could be some overwritten somewhere later?

My *guess* is that something is going wrong in the class somewhere.